# How do I solve this physics slowdown?

Tags: unity, 2d, android, lag

within 10-20 min without touching the android game it would lag. Here is the Unity Profiler Debug.

[image]

This if the fish clicker script where I started noticing lag.

```
public class FishClicker : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask whatIsFish;

[SerializeField]
private float clickRadius = 0.1f;

[SerializeField]
private int coloredFish;
void Update()
{
    var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var hit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(mousePos, clickRadius, whatIsFish);

        if (hit != null)
        {
            if (hit.name == "Blue_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<BlueFishOne>();

                // fish.DoClickThing();
                if (fish != null) 
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 1;
                    //sprint(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Green_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<GreenFishOne>();
                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 2;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Indigo_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<IndigoFishOne>();
                
                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 3;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Orange_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<OrangeFishOne>();

                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 4;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Red_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<RedFishOne>();

                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 5;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Violet_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<VioletFishOne>();

                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 6;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
            else if (hit.name == "Yellow_Fish(Clone)")
            {
                var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<YellowFishOne>();

                if (fish != null)
                {
                    fish.ControlFishClick();
                    coloredFish = 7;
                    //print(fish.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var hit = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(mousePos, clickRadius, whatIsFish);

        if (hit != null)
        {
            if (coloredFish == 1)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Blue_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<BlueFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 2)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Green_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<GreenFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 3)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Indigo_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<IndigoFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 4)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Orange_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<OrangeFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 5)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Red_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<RedFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 6)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Violet_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<VioletFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (coloredFish == 7)
            {
                if (hit.name == "Yellow_Fish(Clone)")
                {
                    var fish = hit.GetComponentInParent<YellowFishOne>();

                    if (fish != null)
                    {
                        fish.ControlFishDrag();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        coloredFish = 0;
    }
}

}
```

This is the fish script for each prefab. BlueFishOne script is for blue fish prefabs and RedFishOne script is for red fish prefabs etc.

```
public class BlueFishOne : MonoBehaviour
{
//public static BlueFishOne instance;

Animator animate;

private Rigidbody2D rigid2D;
private BoxCollider2D box2D;

private Camera myCam;
private Vector3 screenPos;
private float angleOffset;

[SerializeField]
private float speedX, speedY, diveTimer, diveReached,
              clickRadius = 0.1f;

[SerializeField]
private int fishCount = 0, fishColorIs;

[SerializeField]
private bool stopMovement;

[SerializeField]
private LayerMask whatIsFish;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //instance = this;

    animate = GetComponent<Animator>();

    rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    box2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    myCam = Camera.main;

    box2D.enabled = false;
    box2D.enabled = true;
    
    var degrees = Random.Range(0, 361);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, degrees);

    diveReached = Random.Range(1, 4);

    //Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(algae.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>(), GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Diving();
    FishCount();

    //Movement();

    if (!stopMovement)
    {
        Movement();
    }
    else
    {
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        stopMovement = false;
        SnapToPosition();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        stopMovement = false;
        SnapToPosition();
    }

    //print(stopMovement);
}

public void ControlFishClick()
{
    //stopMovement = true;
    screenPos = myCam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 v3 = Input.mousePosition - screenPos;
    angleOffset = (Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) - Mathf.Atan2(v3.y, v3.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

}

public void ControlFishDrag()
{
    stopMovement = true;
    //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector3 v3 = Input.mousePosition - screenPos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(v3.y, v3.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle + angleOffset);
    //print(stopMovement);
}

public void ControlFishUp()
{
    stopMovement = false;
    SnapToPosition();
}

void Diving()
{
    diveTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    if (diveTimer > diveReached)
    {
        GameManager.instance.Dive(animate, "Dive");
    }
}

void FishCount()
{
    if (FishSpawner.instance.fishCount > 0 && fishCount == 0)
    {
        fishCount = FishSpawner.instance.fishCount;
    }
}

void Dive()
{
    animate.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
    //this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(GameManager.instance.xPos, GameManager.instance.yPos);

    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}

void Movement()
{
    float horizontal = speedX * Time.deltaTime;
    float vertical = speedY * Time.deltaTime;

    // 0 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 22.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 0 ||
        transform.eulerAngles.z < 360.0f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 337.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0);
    }

    // 45 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 67.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 22.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 45.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    }

    // 90 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 112.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 67.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 90.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, vertical);
    }

    // 135 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 157.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 112.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 135.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, vertical);
    }

    // 180 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 202.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 157.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 180.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, 0);
    }

    // 225 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 247.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 202.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 225.5f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, -vertical);
    }

    // 270 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 292.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 247.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 270.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, -vertical);
    }

    // 315 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 337.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 292.5f)
    {
        //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 315.0f);
        rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, -vertical);
    }
}

void SnapToPosition()
{
    // 0 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 22.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 0 ||
        transform.eulerAngles.z < 360.0f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 337.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0);
    }

    // 45 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 67.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 22.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 45.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    }

    // 90 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 112.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 67.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 90.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, vertical);
    }

    // 135 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 157.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 112.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 135.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, vertical);
    }

    // 180 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 202.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 157.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 180.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, 0);
    }

    // 225 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 247.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 202.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 225.5f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal, -vertical);
    }

    // 270 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 292.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 247.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 270.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, -vertical);
    }

    // 315 degree
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 337.5f && transform.eulerAngles.z >= 292.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 315.0f);
        //rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, -vertical);
    }

}
}
```

This is the fish food script.

```
public class Algae : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private SpriteRenderer sprite;

[SerializeField]
private CircleCollider2D cir;

[SerializeField]
private float rotationSpeed = 0f, rotTimer, rotTimeReached,
              move, speed, rotateSpeed = 5f, radius = 0.1f, _angle;

[SerializeField]
private bool rotRight = false, xAxis, yAxis;

[SerializeField]
private Vector2 _centre;

[SerializeField]
private int algaeColorIs;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    cir = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
    transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-8.5f, 8.5f), Random.Range(-4.5f, 4.5f));
   
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Spin();
    Movement();
}

void Movement()
{
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -8.5f, 8.5f);
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, -4.5f, 4.5f);

    move = speed * Time.deltaTime; // calculate distance to move
    if (transform.position.x <= -8.5f)
    {
        xAxis = true;
    }
    else if (transform.position.x >= 8.5f)
    {
        xAxis = false;
    }

    if (transform.position.y <= -4.5f)
    {
        yAxis = true;
    }
    else if (transform.position.y >= 4.5f)
    {
        yAxis = false;
    }

    if (xAxis)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(8.5f, transform.position.y), move);
    }
    else if (!xAxis)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(-8.5f, transform.position.y), move);
    }

    if (yAxis)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, 4.5f), move);
    }
    else if (!yAxis)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, -4.5f), move);
    }


}

void Spin()
{
    rotTimer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (rotTimer >= rotTimeReached)
    {
        rotRight = !rotRight;
        rotTimer = 0f;
    }

    if (rotRight)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(0f, 0f, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
    else if (!rotRight)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0f, 0f, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "BlueFish" && 
        this.gameObject.tag == "BlueAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position = 
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f,-9.5f),Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "GreenFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "GreenAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "IndigoFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "IndigoAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "OrangeFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "OrangeAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "RedFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "RedAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "VioletFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "VioletAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
    else if (other.tag == "YellowFish" &&
        this.gameObject.tag == "YellowAlgae")
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.position =
            new Vector2(
                Random.Range(-11.5f, -9.5f), Random.Range(-7.5f, 7.5f)
                );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This piece of code should be fine, but it is calling doclickthing which could potentially cause the issue. Did you run a profiler to see what exactly is calling it to lag?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I left it running 10-20 min without touching the screen and it still lagged. I never used Unity profiler i'll have to read into that.

Comment: In the Unity Profiler between 10-20 min in CPU Usage the Physics color is huge! 2/3rd  the animation color is 1/3rd and garbage collector is tiny.

Comment: My bet is that you're moving a complex collider or many using transforms rather than rigidbodies. Ask about your real problem "How do I solve this physics slowdown" not your guessed-at solution "get rid of layers". Layers are generally good for efficiency by letting the engine reduce the number of candidate bodies to process for a particular event. Edit your question to include your profiling information, and a view of how these fish are set up — their scripts, colliders, Rigidbody, visual appearance, etc.

Comment: I appreciate it.

Comment: Your giant lists of IF clauses look like something you could solve much more simply with an interface, for starters, instead of marshalling string data up out of unmanaged memory a dozen times a frame.

Comment: I think the main problem is rather the object manipulation over the transform. While the huge if block makes it hard to read, from what I read the game lags even when doing nothing. Since the if block needs user interaction, it should not cause the actual lags. Other optimization would be that FishCount function, why does every fish need to do the calculation AND why does it need to be each frame? Just count it once and you are good (add or substract when you create or destroy again). Plus that should happen in a manager and not by every fish.

Comment: I'm not sure how i would put the IF clauses in an interface. I also removed the FishCount function.